# Any way to solve the timezone issue for groupdate?

Tags: chartkick

For chartkick the **groupdate** gem allows to simplify greatly the creation of time related charts. But if for any reason you have a **production** application where **config.active_record.default_timezone is set to :local** and you don't want (or simply can't) change it, you cannot use the gem and most of chartkick (at least to my understanding).

Does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks,
Stefano